# How to get a windows domain server to recognize a linux machine by its name?

Tags: linux, windows, domain

In my company I ran into an issue where we have a linux machine that serves up a Subversion repository. Its hooked up via LDAP to the Active Directory. We got an account setup for an application and they set the Limited Workstations up so it didn't have full access to the network. The problem is that even though the hostname for our machine resolves correctly for me, the credentials for the application account seem to come back as not being allowed based on the name (the error was related to authorized workstations).

I don't have access to any of the domain servers but it might be helpful to come at the management or high-level techs with some ideas, they don't seem to have a solution besides allowing all workstations for the user.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get my linux machine to properly identify itself with the Domain machine by name?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they've restricted the workstation account since linux systems can't fully participate in active directory security policies.  This does not sound like a name resolution issue.